# Qual o erro desse trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tenho essa tabela:

```
create table alecrim(
id_alecrim int not null auto_increment, 
sem_epi int not null,
p1 smallint,
p2 smallint,
p3 smallint,
p4 smallint,
p5 smallint, 
p6 smallint,  
p7 smallint,
p8 smallint,
p9 smallint,
totOvos int,
pend tinyint,
ext tinyint,
ano varchar(4),
primary key(id_alecrim)
) default charset = utf8;
```

E esse trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER somaOvosIFS BEFORE UPDATE
ON alecrim
FOR EACH ROW
DELIMITER \\
    begin
    SET NEW.totOvos = NEW.p1 + NEW.p2 + NEW.p3 + NEW.p4 + NEW.p5 + NEW.p6 + NEW.p7 + NEW.p8 + NEW.p9;
    IF(old.pend > 0) THEN
    NEW.pend = old.pend - 1;
    END IF;
END \\
```

O objetivo do trigger é atualizar os campos em questão(até aí funciona) e se o campo pend for maior que 0 ele atualiza o seu valor com a operação em questão.

Alguém ajuda?

Answer (score 2):

Apenas falta de experiência minha mesmo!

Segue o TRIGGER corrigido:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER somaOvosAlecrim BEFORE UPDATE ON alecrim
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF OLD.pend > 0 THEN
 SET NEW.totOvos = NEW.p1 + NEW.p2 + NEW.p3 + NEW.p4 + NEW.p5 + NEW.p6 + NEW.p7 + NEW.p8 + NEW.p9,
 NEW.PEND = OLD.pend - 1;
 ELSEIF OLD.pend = 0 THEN
 SET NEW.totOvos = NEW.p1 + NEW.p2 + NEW.p3 + NEW.p4 + NEW.p5 + NEW.p6 + NEW.p7 + NEW.p8 + NEW.p9;
 END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Olá Amiraldo. Você pode aceitar a sua própria resposta para marcar que o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Então não é preciso editar o titulo da pergunta?

Comment: Exatamente, não há necessidade de alterar o título Aceitando sua própria resposta (ou a de qualquer outro membro) voce sinaliza que essa resposta resolveu seu problema.